# Cloud Vision API Not Returning Score for WebDetection.WebPage

Tags: google-cloud-vision

Does the Cloud Vision API return a score?

public float getScore()
 Overall relevancy score for the web page.

The [documentation state](http://googleapis.github.io/googleapis/java/proto-google-cloud-vision-v1/0.1.9/apidocs/com/google/cloud/vision/v1/WebDetection.WebPage.html#getScore--)s that it does; however, I have not been able to get a score for any image I submit.  All queries return 0.0, which seems unlikely given the depth of the result list and human verified accuracy that the image does in fact reside on WebPage result.

Pleas advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to follow-up with the internal product team and confirmed that this feature does not return a score value. The API and documentation has been rev'ed accordingly.  If you still see this feature you are using and older version of the API.